# Enable content on row hover in Blazor wasm

Tags: c#, css, web, blazor, hover

I have a Blazor table component with a variable number of rows, based on a collection:

```
<table id="MyTable" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Uploaded By</th>
            <th>Upload Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    @foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>@item.Name</th>
                <th>@item.Description</th>
                <th>@item.UserName</th>
                <th>@item.UploadDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")</th>
                <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => DoSomething()">Do Work</button></th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    }
</table>
```

What I need to do, is enable a specific element, *only* when a mouse hover is actioned on that element's row.

For example, if I have 10 rows in this table (1-10), and I hover over row number 1, only the button on row no.1 should be visible and clickable. The rest of the buttons, who's parent rows are not hovered over, should not be enabled.

How do I enable the button on *only that specific row*, upon hovering over a row, in Blazor?

Comment: Don't do that - anyone who doesn't use a mouse will be excluded from using it

Comment: @MisterMagoo Seems like a valid point. But if not enable on hover, how would one enable on focus? Taking no action is not a solution, as there will be unnecessary elements on screen, that the user is not interested in.

Comment: If the table is going to contain a lot of rows, you don't want Blazor re-rendering it as they move the focus/mouse, so you will either want to render the button(s) on every row and hide/show them using CSS (my preferred approach) with a selector on the `tr` for `hover` and `focus-within` OR if you decide to only render the buttons you will need to add blazor events for `@mouseenter` and `@mouseleave` (mouseover produces a lot of updates - you would need to rate limit) and those event handlers would need to be aware of which row/item they were hovering, which uses a lot of resources.

Comment: Make the entire row clickable.  You can use `@onclick` on any html element, including a normal `<div>` or a table row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are reasons why one would not want to show a child element upon hover mouse hover: It relies on the user using a mouse. Also one could make the entire row clickable, which might be a better user experience.

Though for completeness, here is how to solve the problem I asked about:

In the razor page, add CSS Id selectors to the row (parent) and button (child) HTML tags:

```
@foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        <tbody>
            <tr id="FileTableRow">
                <th>@item.Name</th>
                <th>@item.Description</th>
                <th>@item.UserName</th>
                <th>@item.UploadDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")</th>
                <th><button id="FileTableRowButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => DoSomething()">Do Work</button></th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    }
```

Thereafter, we can use CSS to apply styling to the button (child), whenever there is a hover over the row (parent):

```
#FileTableRowButton {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#FileTableRow {
  &:hover {
    #FileTableRowButton {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  }
}
```

Depending on your use case, you may want to apply different styling. For example, **display: none;** instead of **visibility: hidden;**

Comment: When making these types of CSS changes in Blazor Wasm, make sure to refresh your cache to force the browser to get your CSS changes. You may want to create a custom debug browser in VS with the param (for chrome): ```--disk-cache-dir=null```